# TDengine arithmetic query operation causing coredump using none numeric operands

Tags: sql, time-series, tdengine

I was trying the arithmetic operation using select clause. I found when using numbers as operands the result is looking fine, but none numeric values like string/string or  mix of number/string TDengine core dumps. I was thinking may be the ASCII values could be used in the calculation initially but expecting at least TDengine throws an error. Anyone know if using the none numeric value is the standard way for arithmetic query?

> ```
> taos> select 2 + 3.0 from tb;
>           2 + 3.0          |
> ============================
>                5.000000000 |
>                5.000000000 |
> Query OK, 2 row(s) in set (0.014870s)
>
> taos> select 'a' + 'b' from tb;
> taos: /root/wz_test/TDengine/src/client/src/tscSQLParser.c:3506: functionCompatibleCheck: Assertion `numOfExpr > 0' failed.
> Aborted (core dumped)
>    
> taos> select "a" - 1 from db.tb;
> taos: /root/wz_test/TDengine/src/client/src/tscSQLParser.c:3506: functionCompatibleCheck: Assertion `numOfExpr > 0' failed.
> Aborted (core dumped)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be fixed in the later version.